# Twisted framework Python

Tags: python, twisted

I need some help to get something.I am a newbie in OOP. From what I saw in the documentation of Twisted, more precisely for Protocol class: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.protocol.Protocol.html
I understood that this class is like and interface defining 3 methods which I should override and put code in them as the following classic example shows:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol

class Echo(Protocol):

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)
```

But what I don't get and I couldn't find is how this code runs successfully, when the Protocol class contains no actual code, just a definition of the methods. And how can Protocol be a class and interface at the same time(it is created as Class but contains only definitions of methods)? And where is the actual code which runs and responds to events so it can call the defined methods?

Comment: The main paradgm of Twisted: `don't call us, we'll call you`. So yes, an abstract protocol class shouldn't contain any actual code, just definitions. The "main part of the code" as you call it is [Twisted.Reactor](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.internet.reactor.html). But you shouldn't bother yourself until it's really required, just start coding the _actual_ part of your network service, leaving the rest to the framework.

Comment: What do you mean by "runs successfully"?  This program will do nothing when run.  What do you mean by "no actual code"?  There is a line of "actual" code (by which I take it you mean "implementation of methods": `self.transport.write(data)`.  What do you mean by "it is created as Class"?  In order for this question to be usefully answerable, it has to be a LOT narrower, and include (for example) steps you took to try to work this out and why they didn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out (take from the github page for twisted): https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/trunk/twisted/internet/protocol.py

Protocol is a subclass of BaseProtocol, which is also defined in the same .py file.

```
class Protocol(BaseProtocol):
"""
This is the base class for streaming connection-oriented protocols.
If you are going to write a new connection-oriented protocol for Twisted,
start here.  Any protocol implementation, either client or server, should
be a subclass of this class.
The API is quite simple.  Implement L{dataReceived} to handle both
event-based and synchronous input; output can be sent through the
'transport' attribute, which is to be an instance that implements
L{twisted.internet.interfaces.ITransport}.  Override C{connectionLost} to be
notified when the connection ends.
Some subclasses exist already to help you write common types of protocols:
see the L{twisted.protocols.basic} module for a few of them.
"""

def logPrefix(self):
    """
    Return a prefix matching the class name, to identify log messages
    related to this protocol instance.
    """
    return self.__class__.__name__


def dataReceived(self, data):
    """Called whenever data is received.
    Use this method to translate to a higher-level message.  Usually, some
    callback will be made upon the receipt of each complete protocol
    message.
    @param data: a string of indeterminate length.  Please keep in mind
        that you will probably need to buffer some data, as partial
        (or multiple) protocol messages may be received!  I recommend
        that unit tests for protocols call through to this method with
        differing chunk sizes, down to one byte at a time.
    """

def connectionLost(self, reason=connectionDone):
    """Called when the connection is shut down.
    Clear any circular references here, and any external references
    to this Protocol.  The connection has been closed.
    @type reason: L{twisted.python.failure.Failure}
    """
```